# Simplify multiple layers fractions

Tags: simplifying-expressions, continued-fractions

I have a complicated fraction

```
1/(4 TauTheta)+TauU/(gamma^2 (1+J)^2 TauDelta (1/TauEpsilon+1/(4 TauTheta)+(-1+J)/(4 TauTheta))^2 (TauDelta+TauU/(gamma^2 (1/TauEpsilon+1/(4 TauTheta)+(-1+J)/(4 TauTheta))^2)))-((1+J)^2 TauTheta+4 z1)/(4 (1+J)^2 TauTheta (TauTheta+z1))-TauU/(gamma^2 (1+J)^2 TauDelta (1/TauEpsilon+(-1+J)/(4 TauTheta)+1/(4 (TauTheta+z1)))^2 (TauDelta+TauU/(gamma^2 (1/TauEpsilon+(-1+J)/(4 TauTheta)+1/(4 (TauTheta+z1)))^2)))
```

Here is what it looks like.
[image]

I want to simplify it into a factor with one layer, which means it looks like `a/b`. However, whenever I use `Simplify` or `FullSimplify`, it does not change.

[image]

Could anyone help me? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5):

[`Together`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Together.html) seems to do the trick:

```
FullSimplify@Together@Test
(* (z1 (256 (-1 + J) (3 + 
        J) TauEpsilon^4 TauTheta^4 TauU^2 (TauTheta + z1)^2 + 
     16 gamma^2 TauEpsilon^2 TauTheta^2 TauU (2 TauTheta^2 (J 
TauEpsilon + 4 TauTheta) ((-1 + J) J (3 + J) TauDelta TauEpsilon + 
           4 (-1 + J) (3 + J) TauDelta TauTheta - 
           4 TauEpsilon TauTheta) + 2 TauTheta ((-1 + J) J (3 + J) (-1 + 
              2 J) TauDelta TauEpsilon^2 + 2 (-1 + 4 J) (2 (-1 + J) (3 + J) TauDelta - 
              TauEpsilon) TauEpsilon TauTheta + 32 ((-1 + J) (3 + J) TauDelta - TauEpsilon) TauTheta^2) z1 + (4 TauEpsilon (TauEpsilon 
- 2 J TauEpsilon - 8 TauTheta) TauTheta + (-1 + J) (3 + 
              J) TauDelta ((1 + 2 (-1 + J) J) TauEpsilon^2 + 
              8 (-1 + 2 J) TauEpsilon TauTheta + 32 TauTheta^2)) z1^2) + 
     gamma^4 (-1 + J) (3 + J) TauDelta^2 (J TauEpsilon + 
        4 TauTheta)^2 (-TauEpsilon z1 + J TauEpsilon (TauTheta + z1) + 
        4 TauTheta (TauTheta + z1))^2))/(4 (1 + 
     J)^2 TauTheta (gamma^2 TauDelta (J TauEpsilon + 4 TauTheta)^2 + 
     16 TauEpsilon^2 TauTheta^2 TauU) (TauTheta + 
     z1) (16 TauEpsilon^2 TauTheta^2 TauU (TauTheta + z1)^2 + 
     gamma^2 TauDelta (-TauEpsilon z1 + J TauEpsilon (TauTheta + z1) + 4 TauTheta (TauTheta + z1))^2)) *)
```

You can find this and many other function in the ["Formula Manipulation"](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/FormulaManipulation.html) guide page.